# How is the timing belt changed on vehicles with no timing marks?

Tags: timing-belt, timing

My mechanic was changing the timing on 2010 Hyundai Verna which has a 1.6 DOHC, the timing belt is attached to one cam gear and those cams are connected by a chain from the other end. While an interesting design, there was only 1 mark on the cam that is connected to the timing belt (for TDC I assume). I asked him how does he adjust the timing when the chain between them is removed for maintenance and he literally told me he just tries to make the both cams barely touch the lifters and thus the engine is in time because the cams are exactly opposing each other.

Now my question is, is there a better way to do this? how can the timing be adjusted if an engine has no timing marks? is his method correct? are the camshafts always full 180 degrees from each other?

Comment: I've never worked on that type of car - maybe your mechanic does have some secret knowledge, but personally I'd be checking the Factory Service Manual (failing that, and if I was in very dire straits... the Haynes Manual)

Comment: Why dire lol? I use it for my miata and it is pretty decent

Comment: It was a slight joke - it's better than nothing, but if you're used to a 1,000 page FSM with full line diagrams instead of blurry black and white photos, it's a bit of a step down. I used them for years, but the FSM is always - for me - better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends, while you can time the cams by looking at the cam lobes, there is usually a mark somewhere.  It can be as simple as dots on both cam gears facing each other, a key in the 12 o clock position.  A notch on the end of the cam being in the verticle/horizontal positions.  Back in the day,  i learned from some old timers who didn't use timing marks. And always got it right. So yes, it is possible,  and yes,  especially modern day vehicles have a procedure for this.

Comment: I have used the cam lobe method for many years but takes a trained eye to do this.